# Convert dataframe to json in scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming i have a wordcount example where i get a dataframe as word in one column and wordcount in another column, I want to collect the same and store it as an array of json in mongo collection.

```
eg for dataframe:
|Word  |  Count |
| abc   | 1   |
| xyz   |  23  |
```

I should get the json like:

```
{words:[{word:"abc",count:1},{word:"xyz",count:23}]}
```

When i tried .toJSON on the dataframe and collected the value as list and added it to a dataframe the result which got stored in my mongo was a collection of string rather than collection of JSON.

query used :

```
explodedWords1.toJSON.toDF("words").agg(collect_list("words")).toDF("words")

result : "{\"words\":[{\"word\":\"abc\",\"count\":1},{\"word\":\"xyz\",\"count\":23}]}"
```

I am new to Scala. Any help will be good. (Will be helpful if external package aint used).

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best way to store data from dataframes into Mongo is using the 
MongoDB Spark Connector (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/)

Just add `"org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.2.0"` to your sbt dependencies and check code below

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[2]")
  .appName("test")
  .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/dbname")
  .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/dbname")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val explodedWords1 = List(
  ("abc",1),
  ("xyz",23)
).toDF("Word", "Count")

MongoSpark.save(explodedWords1.write.option("collection", "wordcount").mode("overwrite"))
```

However if you do want the results as a single json *file* then the script below should do it:

```
explodedWords1.repartition(1).write.json("/tmp/wordcount")
```

Finally if you want the json as a list of strings in your scala just use

```
explodedWords1.toJSON.collect()
```

---

Update:

I didn't see that you wanted **all** records aggregated to one field ("words")

If you use the code below, then all three methods above still function (swapping `explodedWords1` with `aggregated`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val aggregated = explodedWords1.agg(
  collect_list(map(lit("word"), 'Word, lit("count"), 'Count)).as("words")
)
```

---

Option 1: `explodedWords1`

[image: explodedWords1]

Option 2: `aggregated`

[image: aggregated]

Comment: option 2 does get me the output in required format. But while adding it as a column to a dataframe to write to mongo DB I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset [words: array<map<string,string>>]" error.

Comment: Did you use the lit() in the agg method?
Otherwise I cannot reproduce this error on Spark 2.3
My code:
https://gist.github.com/TomLous/92e7f3faa9a09c0b8a713159b49785b9

Comment: Thanks Tom Managed to solve the error. Scala is interesting... :) :) Now that the result "aggregated" is a wrapped array of maps as "words", lets say I want to store the value in mongo like the one below: {userid:"Vignesh", words: <our resultant aggregated value>}... How can i do the same.?

Comment: add a `.groupBy('userid)` before the agg

Comment: Can you please vote & accept the answer if you like it?